# Trying to reference an attribute with a variable (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm stuffing around in Python atm and trying to make a little game type thing. Not that much done so far but what I'm hoping for is a combat system allowing you to target specific bodyparts (I've chosen to define them as an object). The following code is meant to take a target unit, a part of that unit and the hand used to attack (in this snippet only the right) and call a method of the target bodypart that will 'damage' it.

```
    def attack(self, target, part, hand):
        if hand == 'right':
             if self.righthand.o <> []:    #this checks if the righthand has a weapon
                 dmg = self.righthand.o[0].getdmg()  #gets damage from the weapon
                 target.part.deltahealth(dmg)  #reduces the bodyparts HP value
```

Now the problem occurs on line 5 of the above. In my head, it's meant to call this for a particular part. Such as target.lefthand.deltahealth(dmg) or target.righthand.deltahealth(dmg)

```
    class Bodypart(object):

        def __init__(self, e, t):
            self.MHP = self.gmh(e,t) #this calculates a health, not relevant really
            self.CHP = self.gmh(e,t)
            self.holding()
            self.status = 'Healthy'

       def deltahealth(self,d):
            self.CHP = self.CHP - d  #specifically this
```

However, it doesn't work because it looks for the bodypart 'part' rather than the value of part. Is there anyway to make this work the way I'm looking for?

Comment: Actually, what is `part`?

Comment: Edit: I'm a dumbo. The solution is right down the bottom. Oops. 

Thank you data! Sorry to everyone trying to understand me :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). In your example above, it should be:

```
getattr(target,part).deltahealth(dmg)
```

Be aware that for this to work, part needs to be a string.

1. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: Thank you so much data, it functions well now.